# Asignar un mensaje y un valor en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy con un trivial en **HTML** y **JavaScript**.

Tengo la siguiente pregunta:

```html
Pregunta 1: ¿Cuál es la capital de España?

<p><input type="submit" value="Madrid">
  <p><input type="submit" value="Zaragoza" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Lleida" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Málaga" /></p>
```

¿Cómo le puedo hacer en JavaScript que al `value="Madrid"` un valor de 2 puntos y al resto 0 puntos? Además de que me salga un `Windows.alert` con el mensaje de correcto.

Comment: Qué es lo que trataste con `Javascript` para solucionar esto?

Comment: Hola Adrohe, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mas sobre el sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Answer (score 0):

La manera en que lo presentas es como un adivina la respuesta. Pero dejar tantos input type submit esta mal. Ten en cuenta que los formularios por lo general llevan un sólo botón ( también lo puedes hacer con solo divs). Te dejo un ejemplo básico y pues ya lo que los demás aporten o tu quieras agregar seria muy bueno...

```js
function getElementsByClassName(root, clss) {

  var result = [],
    els, i;

  if (arguments.length < 2 || !root || !clss || root.nodeType !== 1) {
    return result;
  }

  clss = clss + '';

  if (root.getElementsByClassName) {
    result = root.getElementsByClassName(clss);
  } else if (root.querySelectorAll) {
    result = root.querySelectorAll('.' + clss);
  } else {
    els = root.getElementsByTagName('*');
    clss = " " + clss + " ";
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
      if ((" " + els[i].className + " ").indexOf(clss) !== -1) {
        result.push(els[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var x = getElementsByClassName(document, "js-answ");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
  if (x[i].innerHTML == 'Madrid') {
    alert("Respuesta correcta");
  } else {
    alert("Respuesta incorrecta");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="questions">
  <div>¿Cuál es la capital de España?</div>
  <div id="questions">
    <div class="js-answ btn">Madrid</div>
    <div class="js-answ btn">Zaragoza</div>
    <div class="js-answ btn">Lleida</div>
    <div class="js-answ btn">Málaga</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Solo dentro del for debes hacer el evento click para validar

Comment: ¿Y qué se supone que tiene que hacer tu código? :P

Answer (score 0):

yo propongo la siguiente solución:

```js
function ObtenerRespuesta() {
  const $opcionCorrecta = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="optradio"][data-correct="true"]');
  var mensaje = "";
  var puntos = 0;

  if (!$opcionCorrecta[0].checked)
    mensaje = "Respuesta incorrecta, la respuesta era: " + ($opcionCorrecta[0]).parentNode.innerText + ".";
  else {
    mensaje = "Respuesta correcta.";
    puntos = parseInt(puntos) + parseInt($opcionCorrecta[0].value);
  }

  alert(mensaje + ". Puntos: " + puntos);
}
```

```html
<div class="pregunta">
  <h5>¿Cuál es la capital de España?</h5>

  <label><input type="radio" value="2" name="optradio" data-correct="true">Madrid</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="optradio">Zaragoza</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="optradio">Lleida</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="optradio">Málaga</label>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="ObtenerRespuesta()">Validar</button>
```

la validación la hago con el atributo `data-correct` y la suma de puntos mediante el value del radiobutton.

Espero te sirva!